# Create list in C# with string and int datatypes

Tags: c#

How can I create a list which holds both string value and int value?
Can anyone help me please.Is it possible to create a list with different datatypes?

Comment: for what purpose?  do you mean a key/value pair, or actually storing both types side by side in the list?

Comment: That would be a list of objects List<object> or an ArrayList.....

Comment: @nathan it is for actually storing both datatype values

Comment: @michelle: That doesn't really answer nathan's question very clearly. Both *for the same element* or both for *different* elements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use:

```
var myList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "One");

foreach (var item in myList)
{
    int i = item.Key;
    string s = item.Value;
}
```

or if you are .NET Framework 4 you could use:

```
var myList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
myList.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "One"));

foreach (var item in myList)
{
    int i = item.Item1;
    string s = item.Item2;
}
```

If either the string or integer is going to be unique to the set, you could use:

```
Dictionary<int, string> or Dictionary<string, int>
```

Answer (score 10):

`List<T>` is homogeneous. The only real way to do that is to use `List<object>` which will store any value.

Comment: @AteşGÜRAL that depends entirely on the wider scenario. In many cases, no. But if your requirement **is** to store both things - it isn't *bad* as such. Simply : you need to be a little careful.

Answer (score 3):

You can make have the list contain any object you like. Why don't you create a custom object

### Custom Object

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    public CustomObject()
    {
    }

    public CustomObject(string stringValue, int intValue)
    {
        StringValue = stringValue;
        IntValue = intValue;
    }
}
```

### List Creation

```
List<CustomObject> CustomObject = new List<CustomObject>();
```